# Create a Bluetooth proxy with bluecove and BlueSoleil stack

Tags: java, proxy, bluetooth, bluecove, bluetooth-sco

I have the library http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/ and I have installed BlueSoleil http://www.bluesoleil.com/index.aspx and a compatible bluetooth dongle.

I want to create a Java application (running in Windows 7 x64) that would act as a repeater to boost the signal between my android phone and my hands free device. The hands free device characteristics are:

```
Bluetooth V2.1 compliant
Support Enhanced Data Rate (EDR)
Profiles Supported:
 Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP) 1.2,
 Hands-Free Profile (HFP) 1.5,
 Headset Profile (HSP) 1.1
 Supports Simultaneous Multipoint (two live audio connections)
```

I imagine there are two approaches:

1. The BlueCove Java app would just pair with both devices and act list a client for the phone and as a audio gateway for the hands-free. Then simple pass audio and other data between them as a proxy.
2. The BlueCove Java app would act as a low level protocol proxy, just accepting all requests and forwarding them to another end point device and vise versa.

Some information that may help:

```
HFP
https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/HFP.htm
HSP
https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/HSP.htm
A2DP
https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/A2DP.htm
JSR-82 Sample : SPP Server and Client
http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-spp-server-and-client/
```

Is that possible with bluecove using this stack? Or any other stack?

Comment: Did you make it work?